# How can I recover this delete endpoint, and initialize it within postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, postman

```
I'm developing a Spring Boot application to manage CRUD operations for a "Pessoa" entity. The entity is mapped to a table named "Test" in the database. I have created a Pessoa entity class with the associated getters and setters, a PessoaController class to handle HTTP requests, and a PessoaRepository interface that extends JpaRepository for database operations.
```

Entity:

Constructs a Pessoa with the given parameters.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Test")
public class Pessoa {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "nome", length = 60, nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "doc", length = 14)
    private String documento;

    public Pessoa(Long id, String nome, String documento) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.documento = documento;
    }

    public Pessoa() {
    }

    // Getters and Setters...
}
```

Controller:

Retrieves a list of all pessoas.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/pessoa")
public class PessoaController {

    @Autowired
    private PessoaRepository pessoaRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Pessoa> all() {
        return pessoaRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Pessoa getById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return pessoaRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Pessoa create(@RequestBody Pessoa nova) {
        return pessoaRepository.save(nova);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        pessoaRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @PutMapping
    public void put(@RequestBody Pessoa pessoa) {
        if (pessoa.getId() > 0) {
            pessoaRepository.save(pessoa);
        }
    }
}
```

Repository:

Additional methods for database operations if needed

```
@Repository
public interface PessoaRepository extends JpaRepository<Pessoa, Long> {

}
```

CrudApplication:

Main method to run the Spring Boot application and initialize every crud application.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CrudApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CrudApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I'm facing an issue with the delete endpoint; it doesn't seem to work as expected. Additionally, I'm unsure how to connect and test this CRUD application using Postman. Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can add a ```httpReuqest``` with host + api path , if you deploy application locally , you can try this ```127.0.0.1:8080/pessoa``` , fix the 8080 as your port and this is request should be GET method  aim to invoke ```public List<Pessoa> all() ```

Answer (score 1):

If you have successfully tested the other requests, then you know the base path of the application. You probably run Spring locally, and the address will be `localhost:8080`.

At this address, the method delete is mapped with
`/{id}` resulting, for example, in `localhost:8080/1`  to delete the element with the id equal to 1.

In Postman, make sure to create a DELETE request. Perhaps the reason it's not working for you is that you left it as a POST or another method.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please write your code in English language, because it is more readable for everyone if you need to share your code.

Your put method:

```
@PutMapping
public void put(@RequestBody Pessoa pessoa) {
    if (pessoa.getId() > 0) {
        pessoaRepository.save(pessoa);
    }
}
```

Usually you should check that your entity is not null aside from what you are doing, something like this:

```
@PutMapping
public void put(@RequestBody Pessoa pessoa) {
    if (pessoa.getId() != null && pessoa.getId() > 0) {
        pessoaRepository.save(pessoa);
    }
}
```

When it comes to the delete method, it seems fine, you will need to give us more info on what is not working properly.

For learning Postman please check out their very well done documentation:
[postman documentation](https://learning.postman.com/docs/introduction/overview/)